# Excel IF statement 3 Arguments Parameters

Tags: excel

Can I have some assistance with the excel IF statment that is in a cell.

What is it doing?

What evaluation is done on "`BaselineAmount`"?

```
=IF(BaselineAmount, (Variance/BaselineAmount)*100, (Variance)*100)
```

Comment: what data type is in that cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is checking that BaselineAmount is any value other than blank or 0.  If so, do the TRUE potion, else do the FALSE portion.  Basically it is avoiding division by 0.